# chatbox Botman en facebook e instagram

Tags: chatbox, botman

tengo un chatbox en Botman 2.0 funcionando en facebook menssenger y quería ver la posibilidad de implementarlo en Instagram.  La ayuda de instagram dice esto:

https://help.instagram.com/654906392080948

también me sirve otra solución.